# retrieve value of name attribute of all xsl:element and xsl:attribute tag from xslt document Using java

Tags: java, xslt

I have to print value of name attribut of all xsl:element and xsl:attribute tag from xslt document.

Below is my sample xsl:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="*">
<xsl:element name="TransactionDateTime">
<xsl:value-of select="@TRANSACTIONDATETIME"/>
</xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="ChangeIndicator">
<xsl:value-of select="@CHANGEINDICATOR"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried using dom parser but it does not give me desired output.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = 
              DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            org.w3c.dom.Document doc = builder.parse("C:/sample_xslt.txt");

            NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
            System.out.println("XML Elements: ");
            for (int i=0; i<list.getLength(); i++) {

                Element element = (Element)list.item(i);
                System.out.println(element.getNodeName());
            }
```

Output i get is :

xsl:stylesheet
xsl:strip-space
xsl:template
xsl:element
xsl:element

Expected output is :

TransactionDateTime
ChangeIndicator

Comment: Please post the expected result **as code** - and explain where exactly you're having a difficulty with this.

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should show us your code and explain your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this answer with the simple XPath 2.0 expression `//(xsl:element|xsl:attribute)/@name` - using DOM is total overkill for this.

Comment: I tried this but it is not giving me any output. In below answer i have posted the code that i have tried